# Why is there a 地 in (霉)旧地席的气味?

Tags: word-choice, particles

From the second chapter in George Orwell's 1984, using the translations at [Douban](https://book.douban.com/review/4592249/):

> [*Original*](http://www.george-orwell.org/1984/0.html): The hallway smelt of boiled cabbage and old rag mats.
>   *Translation 1*: 门厅里有一股熬白菜和**旧地席的气味**
>   *Translation 2*: 一进门厅就闻到煮卷心菜和**霉旧地席的气味**

**Question**: Why is there a 地 in (霉)旧地席的气味?

It seems like it should be a 的, not a 地.  My understanding is that (霉)旧 (old) is an adjective describing the noun 席 (mat), and thus [it should be 的](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Structural_particle_%22de%22#.E7.9A.84_.28de.29_Before_Nouns).

Comment: 地席 is 铺在地上的席子, a mat.

Comment: BTW, 地席, (Di xí), is floor mat, and 地毯, (Dì tǎn), is carpet. As for the 席, it also means banquet / feast as in the old days people sat on floor mats to eat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「地」 is not a particle here. The word for *rag mats* is translated as the two-character word 「地席」, literally *mat* (席) for the *floor* (地).

> ...舊地席的气味
>
> ...*smelt* (气味) *of* (的) ... *old* (舊) *rag mats* (地席).

Comment: Oh okay, thanks---that makes a lot more sense.

Comment: I personally don't see the reason to use the super common characters 地 and 得 for words which are pretty much cognate to 的, but that's the state of our current writing system =,=

Comment: Some people consider that sophistication is directly proportional to complexity?

Answer (score 1):

地席 is a two character word meaning floor mat.

The 霉 in 霉旧地席 refers to the old mat being mouldy and/or having a musky smell.